# My Android app database access works in emulator but getting null values in production

Tags: android

I created an app with tabs which has insert/read access to database. In emulator it works fine (it can read/display/insert data) but when I publish it and installed in my device, it keeps crashing. Anyone have experience similar problem and have fix it? Thanks in advance.

In app feedback, I am seeing "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"

Comment: what is the logs when it crashes? We need more information to help

Comment: Thanks. This is the error in the android feedback (when app crashes) -  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: can you post the rest of the log, it should tell you what is throwing that error

Comment: Thanks. Already fixed the issue. Basically, the problem is related to parsing of JSON. Seems GSON API is not working in Android?

Comment: GSON does work, possibly your model did not match what you expected?